# Populate a readonly property using Beanutils or related classes

Tags: java, properties, readonly, apache-commons-beanutils

Does Beanutils or any associated classes provide a method to populate a readonly property like the example below?

```
class MyBean {
    private String check;

    public String getCheck() {
        return check;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setCheck(String check) {
        this.check = check;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: and i am wondering how hibernate populates the value for a property like check even though the setter is private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting this question actually this can be achieved using reflection and not beanUtils,

```
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        Class<?> c = bean.getClass();
        Field f = c.getDeclaredField("id");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(bean, 12346l);
```

This is what i was looking for.

Vaibhav